# Lucene.NET problem with Lucene.Version on .NET Framework 4.5.1

Tags: c#, .net, lucene.net

I try to install Lucene.NET version 4.8.0-beta000016 on .NET Framework 4.5.1 everything is good BUT when i try to start the application return error:

```
System.IO.FileLoadException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'Lucene.Net, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=85089178b9ac3181' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)'
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I just created a console application using .NET Framework 4.5.2 and used NuGet to add Lucene.NET 4.8.0-beta00016.  The solution compiles without error.  Please retry in isolation, I think you will find that it works.

[image]

[image]